# Make dropdownlist on ribbon visible only on wikipages library

Tags: 2010, ribbon, wiki

I am following this tutorial.

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Creating-a-SharePoint-2010-Ribbon-extension-part-1.aspx

However I need that the dropdownlist can only be seen in wiki pages library. I suppose it should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this in the elements file under CustomActions as a parameters:

RegistrationType="List" 
RegistrationId="119"

The number 119 referes to a WebPageLibrary ("Wiki Library" (also “Site Pages” in 2010))

More information here:
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2008/01/sharepoint-registrationid-list-template.html

PS: it might also be possible without the RegistrationType="List".